# Can't modify variable of a class from closure

Tags: swift, class, variables, closures, self

I want decodedResult variable assigns to exchangeInformations variable:
self.exchangeInformations = decodedResult

I created an instance of exchangeInfo() class. I try print the value of the exchangeInformations variable but I got nil. Why?

```
import Cocoa

class exchangeInfo {

    var exchangeInformations: exchangeInformation? //Exchange information
    let exchangeInformationURL: String = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
    
    struct exchangeInformation: Codable {
        var timezone: String //UTC
        var serverTime: Int //1565246363776
        var rateLimits: [rateLimits] = []//Rate limits
        var exchangeFilters: [exchangeFilters] = [] //Exchange filters
        var symbols: [symbols] //Symbols
    }
    
    struct rateLimits: Codable { //Rate limits
        var rateLimitType: String //REQUEST_WEIGHT, ORDERS, RAW_REQUESTS
        var interval: String //interval
        var intervalNum: UInt16 //1
        var limit: UInt32 //1200
    }
    
    struct exchangeFilters: Codable {
        var filterType: String
        var minPrice, maxPrice, tickSize, multiplierUp, multiplierDown, minQty, maxQty, stepSize, minNotional, maxPosition: String?
        var avgPriceMins, limit, maxNumOrders, maxNumAlgoOrders, maxNumIcebergOrders: UInt16?
        var applyToMarket: Bool?
    }
    
    struct symbols: Codable { //Symbols
        var symbol: String //ETHBTC
        var status: String //TRADING
        var baseAsset: String //ETH
        var baseAssetPrecision: UInt16 //8
        var quoteAsset: String //BTC
        var quotePrecision: UInt16 //8
        var quoteAssetPrecision: UInt16 //8
        var baseCommissionPrecision: UInt16 //8
        var quoteCommissionPrecision: UInt16 //8
        var orderTypes: [String] //orderTypes
        var icebergAllowed: Bool //true
        var ocoAllowed: Bool //true
        var quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed: Bool //true
        var isSpotTradingAllowed: Bool //true
        var isMarginTradingAllowed: Bool //true
        var filters: [exchangeFilters] = [] //Filters
        var permissions: [String] //Permissions
    }
    
    init() {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: exchangeInformationURL) else {
            print("URL is not valid")
            return
        }
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        
        session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            do {
                if let adat = data {
                    
                    if let decodedResult = try? JSONDecoder().decode(exchangeInformation.self, from: adat) {
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            self.exchangeInformations = decodedResult
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

var informacio = exchangeInfo()


if let serverTime = informacio.exchangeInformations?.serverTime {
    print (serverTime)
}
```

I got nothing.

Comment: `if let decodedResult = try? JSONDecoder().decode(exchangeInformation.self, from: adat)`: Silencing the `try?`, ie, if the nex method throws an error, even if it's could you information on why it failed, I don't want to here about it. Please, don't. Do a proper do/try/catch. Also, your method is async. Add a print before `self.exchangeInformations = decodedResult`, like `print("Got decodedResult: \(decodedResult)")` and one just after `var informacio = exchangeInfo()`: `var informacio = exchangeInfo(); `print("Just init the informacio")`, which one is printed first?

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the try? to try now. If I printed self.exchangeInformations in DispatchQueue.main.async {) than it worked. All data printed to console. But if it printed in the end of the code (after creating class instance: informacio.exchangeInformations) than I got nil.

Comment: Question: The print inside `DispatchQueue.main.async {)` was BEFORE or AFTER the other one? Which one did you expect to be first? That's the asynchrone concept you are missing.

Comment: In the DispatchQueue.main.async worked before and after, too. In this block I can print to the console the self.exchangeInformations variable or decodedResult. It worked before, too. But on the end of the code (var informacio = exchangeInfo(), informacio.exchangeInformations ) it's not.

Comment: Here is not working: DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            self.exchangeInformations = decodedResult
                            
                        }
                        print (self.exchangeInformations)

Comment: Here is not working, too: print (self.exchangeInformations)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            self.exchangeInformations = decodedResult
                            
                        }

Comment: Here it is working: DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            
                            self.exchangeInformations = decodedResult;

                            print (self.exchangeInformations)
                            
                        }

Comment: You don't seem to understand: Check this https://pastebin.com/WnhJ3N0X If you check that, what will be printed first? What will be in fact be printed first? When you are accessing `serverTime` has the value been set already or not?

Comment: Sorry for my English . The value of serverTime has been set in the init() func in the class by loading from a remote server (API).

Comment: Did you try with the prints I put in the pastebin? Which one appear first in console? You don't seem to understand that the closure of the `dataTask(with:completion;)` will be called AFTER your line trying to access to `serverTime`. Try my code, see the output in console.

Comment: On Pastebin I got only a 403 forbidden message.

Comment: https://controlc.com/b04d6701 ?

Comment: Ok, I understand. I writed a print code direct after self.exchangeInformations = decodedResult (print 1), and an other after the var informacio = exchangeInfo() (print 2). After running the code I got first the print 2, and then the print 1 message.

Comment: The problem is the async. What is the solution? How can I print variables of exchangeInfo() after remote loading?

Comment: Thanks the code, Larme. I tried it. I got these: exchangeInfo has been created
After trying to access to serverTime
dataTask(with:completion: closure
Will set self.exchangeInformations with exchangeInformation(timezone: "UTC" .......